# What is a JS regular expression for getting a sub string of the below?

Tags: javascript, regex, events, dom-events

I have the following applied to a string:

```
function onclick(event) {
showOverlay('overlayWrapper', 'overlayIframe', 'http://www.bestinvest.co.uk');
}
```

and I wish to be able to get an array of the 3 arguments in the string, so I can use (for example)....

```
newArray[0] //<= returns 'overlayWrapper'

newArray[2] //<= returns 'http://www.bestinvest.co.uk'
```

Can using a regular expression help? if so how? I want to make the code as small as possible.

For clarity, the above function is placed within an `onClick` event applied directly to a link tag. I am capturing the string and then wish to get the 3 arguments.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. You already have the three strings separated. So why do need regular expressions then?

Comment: What does your string look like? Example of input and output would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Without any messy regex/string parsing:**

```
var str = "function onclick(event) { showOverlay('overlayWrapper', 'overlayIframe', 'http://www.bestinvest.co.uk'); }";

function showOverlay() {
 alert('this is the original overlay function and should not be called by the below!');
}

(function() {
  function showOverlay(wrapper, iframe, url) {
    //access arguments directly or by arguments[0] arguments[1] etc.
    alert(wrapper);
  };

  eval('('+str+')()');
})();
```

Comment: Hi Gary, this did work in the end although the use of eval() is not great, but a dirty quick way of doing it. I did route for in the end the followin code....
var a;
function showOverlay(){ a = arguments;}
eval('('+trigger.attr('onclick')+')()');

using some jquery there.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes eval() can be nasty, but as long as you trust the source, using this method should be safe. As an extra layer of security showOverlay above is wrapped in it's own little bubble (closure), so it cannot access anything outside of it.

Comment: my thoughts entirely on the closure. thanks for the help on this, kicked my brain into assessing the best way possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cheeky way of doing what you want:

```
var str = "function onclick(event) { showOverlay('overlayWrapper', 'overlayIframe', 'http://www.bestinvest.co.uk'); }"

var str2 = str.replace("function onclick(event) { showOverlay(", "new Array(").replace("); }", ")");
var newArray = eval(str2);

alert(newArray[0]);
alert(newArray[1]);
alert(newArray[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming there is nothing else in the onclick, and 'subject' is the variable holding the onlick contents you grabbed...

```
var newArray = subject.match(/'([^']+)'/g);
```

Comment: I hope the url doesn't contain `'` otherwise this will screw up ;-)

Comment: this was not the best way as I have found IE to have the single quote character when taking the onclick as a string, and it applies not an "onclick" function name but an "anonymous" function name. But it will be useful in the future thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "function onclick(event) { showOverlay('overlayWrapper', 'overlayIframe', 'http://www.bestinvest.co.uk'); }";
var result = str.match(/'[^']*'/g);
```

this results in the array:

```
['overlayWrapper','overlayIframe','http://www.bestinvest.co.uk']
```

**Update** - it actually results in the array:

```
["'overlayWrapper'","'overlayIframe'","'http://www.bestinvest.co.uk'"]
```

The single quotes are part of the result, so you have to strip them afterwards.